# Insert failed method is not found

Tags: jquery, html, meteor

Jquery

```
DiceResults = new Mongo.Collection("dice");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("dice");
    Template.boardGame.events({

        'click #roll' : function() {
            var dice = $('.die').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('src')
            }).get();
            for(var z =0; z<dice.length; z++){
                DiceResults.insert({
                    sides:dice[z]
                });

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Server side

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("dice",function(){
        return DiceResults.find();
    });

};
```

On the client side it map the variable dice to 6 images with the class die. From there I would use a loop to insert everything from the array dice to DiceResults. Yet I get insert failed method is not.
Help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure this this line:

```
DiceResults = new Mongo.Collection("dice");
```

appears in common code (code that runs on both the server and the client).

In order to do this, make sure that it runs in a file outside of the client/ or server/ directories.

Comment: ok I made a file called both.js in the lib directory and it will still give me that same error

Comment: the same exact error?  or is it an error saying "not allowed" (which could mean you need to set up allow/deny rules..assuming you've removed 'insecure' package)?

Comment: ok.  it still seems like somehow the DiceResults collection is not being defined on both client and server.  I would try running DiceResults.find() on the meteor shell and in the browser console.  Both should return a cursor (even if its empty)

Comment: ok got it working had to put  DiceResult in both server and client js files